# Visual Studio could not load System.Interactive.Async

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, discord.net

I am writing a Discord bot using the Discord.NET API wrapper but for some reason, whenever I try and run the code, it crashes on the line

```
new Program().StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

which is the line that starts the bot. `System.Interactive.Async` is included in the solution's references and is up-to-date as of the NuGet Package Manager. I have already tried adding

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Interactive.Async" publicKeyToken="94bc3704cddfc263" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.3000.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
```

to the app.config however, this did not solve my issue. The solution is running .NET framework 4.6.1.

Image of the error:

[image]

Comment: For me I discovered that I had multiple versions of System.Interactive.Async referenced across different .csprojs. Unifying the references solved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the issue. The dll file was  corrupted, so I just asked a friend to send me a copy of theirs.